# Redirect request to another domain with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible in Apache to redirect a request from my domain: `www.example.com/index.html` to another domain `http://www.other-domain.com/page/info` as if I was directly visiting that page?

So the user shouldn;t notice anything. He should simply think he's visiting `www.example.com`, while apache serves back the content of `http://www.other-domain.com/page/info`.

This is because the other domain is the new server, and the users should be able to visit the old URL as well. Note, ***I dont want to do a 301 redirect***.

I know this can be done with `VirtualHost`, but my web host doesn't allow me to use that. I can use `mod_rewrite`, so I'm hoping I can do the same trick with that.

Anyone any idea if t his is possible, and if so, how to do it?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/index.html$  http://www.other-domain.com/page/info [PT]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to achieve this is by **enabling `mod_proxy` on `www.example.com`**. Once `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrute` are enabled place this rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` of `www.example.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?(index\.html)?$ http://www.other-domain.com/page/info [L,P]
```